# Objects in Smarty dynamic select field

Tags: php, smarty

I want to create a select dropdown list populated with the Categories array that I put inside an array.

`$contents` is an array whose entries are automatically assigned in smarty.

```
foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {
    $this->_smarty->assign($key, $value);
}
```

**Controller.php:**

```
private $contents;

public function createStart() {
    $categories = $service->listCategories();
    $this->contents['categories'] = $categories;

    return 'documentsform-view';
}
```

**html view:**

```
<select>
  {html_options options=$categories}
</select>
```

This doesn't work.

Categories are objects. I want my options values to take each category ID, and to show each category name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved with a smarty `foreach`:

```
<select>
  {foreach item=category from=$categories}
    {html_options values=$category->getId() output=$category->getName()}
  {/foreach}
</select>
```